# How to alter android opera lock screen news?

Tags: opera-browser

**How to alter android opera lock screen news?**

When my android os7 is now unlocked there is the Opera browser lock screen news. How can one alter the content displayed there?

Comment: Do you want to fully remove it, or are you looking to change things around?

Comment: Change things around; like change the content shown. I kinda like the large clock displayed. Both of them are probably in the same spot though. Thank you A. bochur.

Comment: Oh, I see. There is no apparent way to do that, but you can always look for a different app that gives you something similar

Answer (score 0):

Find this apk "com.google.android.deskclock-3.0.0.apk" on some mirror that has "old" versions. It's the one with the black clock face, not the white, or light coloured one. Save the apk, and you can then always restore a good size clock widget to your home screen.

Careful, a number of these mirrors have tons of click-bait. apkmirror.com seems to be fine.  So Google search the apk.  Go to the apkmirror.com result.  Then click "DOWNLOAD APK".  NOW WAIT, it takes quite a few seconds, but the site does come back to ask where you want to save the file.

And do save the file, don't just install it, because the next "update" or "upgrade" from Google may overwrite the clock. Also, I suggest, save it to your SD card, so that, in the unlikely event, when you have to do a factory reset, the file is not lost.  Once saved on your device, you can install the apk.  Now you have to drag a widget to the home screen.  As widget you have a choice of circular face or digital.

BTW, this widget will also give you back the circular "time picker" for setting your alarm clock.

Comment: I use the same policy for other apps that I like.  I save the apk, in case I don't like the next version that may inadvertently get installed during an update or an upgrade.